# Class not found org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor in Spring XD module using Spring Kafka Integration with XML configuration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd, spring-kafka

I am receiving the follow exception when I try construct a Kafka consumer in my xd module:

```
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:702) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:557) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:73) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:69) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:284) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:222) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:179) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:204) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor ClassNotFoundException exception occured
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:227) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:637) ~[na:na]
... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:332) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:225)
```

Here is my xml:

```
<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="kafkaListener" listener-container="customKafkaMessageListenerContainer"
    auto-startup="false" phase="100" send-timeout="5000" channel="toTransformer"
    error-channel="errorChannel"/>

<bean id="containerProps"
    class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties">
    <constructor-arg name="topicPartitions" ref="topicPartitionInitialOffset" />
</bean>

<bean id="topicPartitionInitialOffset"
    class="org.springframework.kafka.support.TopicPartitionInitialOffset">
    <constructor-arg index="0" name="topic" value="source-8-26"
        type="java.lang.String" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" name="partition" value="0"
        type="int" />
    <constructor-arg index="2" name="initialOffset" value="0"
        type="java.lang.Long" />
</bean>

<bean id="consumerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
            <entry key="group.id" value="test-consumer-group" />
            <entry key="autocommit.enable" value="false" />
            <entry key="value.deserializer" value-type="java.lang.Class" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer">
            </entry>
            <entry key="key.deserializer" value-type="java.lang.Class" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer">
            </entry>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="customKafkaMessageListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer">
    <constructor-arg name="consumerFactory" ref="consumerFactory">
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="containerProperties" ref="containerProps" />
</bean>
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this class not found exception? I checked the API for Kafka 0.10.0 and the class exists, so I'm not sure why I am receiving this exception.  Could it have to do with how Spring XD loads the classes?  I know that Spring XD comes with Kafka 0.8.2 in its lib folder, so maybe Spring XD is loading Kafka 0.8.2 first and then its unable to find the class because of that?

Any insight would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to work ok because the module is loaded in its own classloader which should find the right classes from the module's lib folder.

I usually debug this kind of problem by running the JVM with `-verbose` which logs all the class loading.

Note: if you are using Kafka for the XD transport, Spring XD only supports the 0.8.x.x client - the follow-on projects (Spring Cloud Stream/Spring Cloud Dataflow) will support the newer kafka clients. The [first milestone of version 1.1 supporting the new clients was announced last week](https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/26/spring-cloud-stream-brooklyn-m1-is-available).

Comment: So if its not a XD class loading issue, then do you think I have some processing out of order in the code that I posted?  I keep getting this exception and drawing blanks as to why and could really use your help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't speculate; as I said `-verbose` is your friend.

Comment: I tried using -verbose by running the command jar -jar myXDModule.jar -verbose:class and I get the error: "no main manifest attribute, in myXDModule.jar".  Since my XD module has no main class how would I use verbose to debug?

Comment: No; you need to run the XD container's JVM with `-verbose` so you can see the class loading at runtime.